# how to set getCreatedAt(); date object in android textview?

Tags: java, android, datetime, date

how do you set the twitter4j date object in android? seems pretty straight forward in java but cant make this work on android, the twitter4j javadoc can be found here http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/Status.html

```
Date tweettime = result.getCreatedAt();
textview.setText(""+ tweettime);
```

Comment: Making my own Twitter App, i used [PrettyTime](http://ocpsoft.com/prettytime/) Since I can format the recent dates like "a few seconds ago", etc

Answer (score 2):

Showing a date on Android is hardly different from showing it in a JVM.
Just use a [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to specify the format of the date. Also, make sure that any UI changes (to your textview) are done on the UI Thread.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter4j has a friendly helper class to transform the date created Date object into something more user readable.  It's close to the format twitter uses to show the date;
I made a method you can use:

```
/*converts standard date to user readable date such as 5m ago, 30 mins ago, 1 hr ago etc*/
private String formatDate(Date create_date){

//twitter date format from json response:  Wed Jul 31 13:15:10 EDT 2013
TimeSpanConverter converter = new TimeSpanConverter(); 
return converter.toTimeSpanString(create_date);

}
```

You will need to import:  `import twitter4j.util.TimeSpanConverter;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TimeSpanConverter converter = new TimeSpanConverter();
```

`dateTextView.setText(converter.toTimeSpanString(status.getCreatedAt()));`